# Query with wp_pagenavi?

Tags: php, wordpress

I use the following code to query all the posts

```
<?php
$paged = get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
query_posts(array(
'post_type'         => 'san-pham',                          'posts_per_page'    => 8,
'paged'         => $paged,
'order'         => 'DESC',
)
);
?>
<?php $i=1; while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
//
<?php $i++; endwhile ?>
<?php if (function_exists('wp_pagenavi')) {
wp_pagenavi(); } ?>
```

Now I want to query all the post from a specific category. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the category_name in the query_posts array

For example

query_posts('showposts=3&category_name=Blog&orderby=ID&paged='.$paged);

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
    $paged = get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
        $args = array(
        'post_type'  => 'san-pham',  
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'paged'         => $paged,
        'posts_per_page' => 8,
        'order'         => 'DESC',
);
    $query = new WP_Query($args);  
        if ($query->have_posts()):
            while ( $query->have_posts() ):
                $query->the_post(); 
?>      
        //content
 <?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php if (function_exists('wp_pagenavi')): ?>
        <?php wp_pagenavi( array( 'query' => $query ) ); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```